# Between Clause For dates not working in Impala

Tags: impala

My table EMPLOYEE contains loaddate column having string datatype.

In this column dates are stored like

```
'2019-12-8',
'2019-12-9',
'2019-12-10',
'2019-12-11',
'2019-12-12',
'2019-12-13',
'2019-12-14',
'2019-12-15',
```

when I am running below query

```
SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-8' and '2019-12-14';
```

I am getting 0 records.
But when I am running below query getting records but only from 2019-12-10 to 2019-12-14' though table contains records for 8 & 9

```
SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-08' and '2019-12-14';
```

The difference between above two queries is 2019-12-8 and 2019-12-08.
So don't understand why first query is not giving any record while second query is giving records but not all.

Comment: Store and provide your dates as proper `DATE` columns/values instead of strings. `2019-12-8` isn't a valid date.

Comment: @ceejayoz Impala does not support date datatype

Comment: https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_literals.html 

`The DATE literals are in the form of DATE'YYYY-MM-DD'. For example, DATE '2013-01-01'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in understanding of below parts.

**1. Between operator functionality.**

Refer : [impala between operator](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_operators.html#between)

```
BETWEEN Operator : expression BETWEEN lower_bound AND upper_bound

a. In a WHERE clause, compares an expression to both a lower_bound and upper_bound. 
b. The comparison is successful if the expression is greater than or equal to the lower_bound, and less than or equal to the upper_bound. 
c. If the bound values are switched, so the lower_bound is greater than the upper_bound, does not match any values.
```

**2. datatype used is string but between operator is typically used with numeric data types as per the documentation.**

**3. order by of the loaddate**

Clearly the value '2019-12-8' is greater than '2019-12-15' in the ascending order. Insert two more values '2019-12-08' and '2019-12-09' they will come at the top when same order by query is run since they will be less than '2019-12-10'.

```
SELECT loaddate FROM employee order by loaddate;
'2019-12-10'
'2019-12-11'
'2019-12-12'
'2019-12-13'
'2019-12-14'
'2019-12-15'
'2019-12-8'
'2019-12-9'

SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-8' and '2019-12-14'; ---zero results because lower_bound('2019-12-8') is the larger value than upper_bound('2019-12-14'). (case c)

SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-08' and '2019-12-14'; ---getting records from 2019-12-10 to 2019-12-14 because 08 and 09 don't exist.

SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-08' and '2019-12-9'; ---this will fetch all the data in the sample considering 10 is greater than 08(assuming 08 and 09 are not inserted yet).
```

Comment: the issue is fixed inserted the data in YYYY-MM-DD format with string data type and below query works perfectly.                                                                                
SELECT * FROM employee where loaddate between '2019-12-08' and '2019-12-14'.